# How to set the dtype of a numpy 2d array of [int, float]?

Tags: python, numpy

Could someone tell me what's wrong with this code:

```
import numpy as np

# Create an empty list
mylist = []
# append a variable number of 2d tuples to it, this might be a loop
mylist.append([0, 3.0])
mylist.append([1, 2.5])
print(mylist)
# Convert list to a numpy 2d array
mat = np.array(mylist)
print(mat)
dtype = [('A', 'int'), ('B', 'float')]
# Convert list to a numpy 2d array of [int, float]
mat = np.array(mylist, dtype = dtype)
print(mat)
```

When I convert my list of lists to a numpy array, both entries become float.
I'd like to keep the first entry of each item int and the second float.
Here's the output I get:

```
[[0, 3.0], [1, 2.5]]
[[ 0.   3. ]
 [ 1.   2.5]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dtype_test.py", line 10, in <module>
    mat = np.array(mylist, dtype = dtype)
TypeError: expected a readable buffer object
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't get an error, try to update your python

Comment: Works for me as well on Python 3.

Comment: Thanks for checking. My python version is Python 2.7.12, came with Ubuntu 16.04.5

Comment: `mylist` should be a list of tuples not a list of lists.

Comment: Your code works without errors in python 2.7.10 and 2.7.15 but yields a different output. I do not understand how it can do that i n python 2.7.12.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [439]: mylist
Out[439]: [[0, 3.0], [1, 2.5]]
In [440]: mat
Out[440]: 
array([[0. , 3. ],
       [1. , 2.5]])
In [441]: np.array(mylist, dtype)
Out[441]: 
array([[(0, 0. ), (3, 3. )],
       [(1, 1. ), (2, 2.5)]], dtype=[('A', '<i8'), ('B', '<f8')])
```

Note that numbers have been duplicated in the structured array.

If instead we provide a list of tuples (notice how the display of a structured array uses tuples):

```
In [442]: mytup = [tuple(row) for row in mylist]
In [443]: mytup
Out[443]: [(0, 3.0), (1, 2.5)]
In [444]: np.array(mytup, dtype)
Out[444]: array([(0, 3. ), (1, 2.5)], dtype=[('A', '<i8'), ('B', '<f8')])
In [445]: _['A']
Out[445]: array([0, 1])
```